# How can I calculate the moments of a truncated random variable?

Tags: random, distributions

I am using the [Moment function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Moment.html) to calculate the moments of an exponential random variable.

as follows,

```
Moment[ExponentialDistribution[3], 9]
```

However, I need to calculate the moments of a truncated (between 0 and 5) exponential random variable as well, however, I have checked the available documentation and I don't find anything. Can someone please tell me what I have to add to my current code for it to be truncated in the interval [0, 5]?

Comment: Try: Moment[TruncatedDistribution[{0, 5}, ExponentialDistribution[3]], 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

More generally, the truncated distribution is given by

```
tdist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, xmax}, ExponentialDistribution[λ]];
```

`tdist` inherits the assumption on the parameter for `ExponentialDistribution` and adds the assumption that `xmax` is positive real.

```
dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[tdist]

(* λ > 0 && Im[xmax] == 0 && xmax > 0 *)
```

The PDF is

```
PDF[tdist, x]
```

[image]

Verifying the `PDF`

```
Assuming[dpa,
 Integrate[PDF[tdist, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

The moments are then

```
Moment[tdist, r]

(* (λ^-r (Gamma[1 + r] - 
   Gamma[1 + r, xmax λ]))/(1 - E^(-xmax λ)) *)

CentralMoment[tdist, r]

(* (1/(-1 + E^(xmax λ)))E^(-1 + (1 + 
     1/(-1 + E^(xmax λ))) xmax λ) λ^-r (Gamma[
    1 + r, -1 + (xmax λ)/(-1 + E^(xmax λ))] - 
   Gamma[1 + r, -1 + (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(xmax λ))) xmax λ]) *)
```

For example,

```
Assuming[dpa,
 #[tdist] & /@ {Mean, Moment[#, 1] &, Moment[#, 2] &,
   Variance, CentralMoment[#, 2] &}]
```

[image]